# Crash on New Activity's Call to OnCreate

Tags: android, xml

In starting my activity called Home Screen, the app crashes in trying to read the XML file at line 36, with the following error:

```
    Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment

    <fragment
    android:name="com.example.myName.myApp.EventsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/events_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="464dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

The top line is line 36, which defines a fragment within my home screen activity xml file. Below is the stack trace for the execution so far.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.myName.myApp, PID: 15937
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether/com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether.HomeScreen@d0dbff6 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                  at com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether.EventsFragment.onAttach(EventsFragment.java:83)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1372)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:24)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Could you post the crash stack trace?

Comment: @shhp Added! Thanks so much for bothering to look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your `HomeScreen. Java` activity. That listener implementation is missing due to which you are getting that crash.

This log is clearly stating that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.braedanshigley.feelbettertogether.HomeScreen@d0dbff6 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I feel silly for not looking closely :P

Answer (score 0):

Hello does your fragment name package correct?
com.example.myName.myApp.EventsFragment this one need to be the one on top of the Fragment class